# How to pick up the elements has similar name in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, filter

I have a list:

```
['15g', 'engout', 'ImpactTphase.py', 'LANL.INI', 'OUTGRAF.TXT', 'OUTPAR.TXT', 'par.bat', 'pargraf1.BAT', 'parphase.py', 'RFFLD000.TBL', 'RFFLD010.TBL', 'sp4.acc', 'Tablplot.log', 'tape2.t2', 'tape3.t3', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE185.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE190.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE195.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE200.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE205.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE210.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE215.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE220.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE225.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE230.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE235.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE240.TBL', 'TplotPRF.TXT']
```

In python, how could I pick up the elements has `TIMESTEPEMITTANCE???.TBL`. Also how I can separate "TIMESTEPEMITTANCE???" into "TIMESTEPEMITTANCE"and "???"?
THanks,

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`fnmatch.fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch):

```
>>> lst = [
    '15g', 'engout', 'ImpactTphase.py', 'LANL.INI', 'OUTGRAF.TXT', 'OUTPAR.TXT',
    'par.bat', 'pargraf1.BAT', 'parphase.py', 'RFFLD000.TBL', 'RFFLD010.TBL',
    'sp4.acc', 'Tablplot.log', 'tape2.t2', 'tape3.t3', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE185.TBL',
    'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE190.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE195.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE200.TBL',
    'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE205.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE210.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE215.TBL',
    'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE220.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE225.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE230.TBL',
    'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE235.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE240.TBL', 'TplotPRF.TXT'
]
>>> import fnmatch
>>> [x for x in lst if fnmatch.fnmatch(x, 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE???.TBL')]
['TIMESTEPEMITTANCE185.TBL',
 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE190.TBL',
 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE195.TBL',
 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE200.TBL',
 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE205.TBL',
 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE210.TBL',
 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE215.TBL',
 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE220.TBL',
 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE225.TBL',
 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE230.TBL',
 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE235.TBL',
 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE240.TBL']
```

For the second question, if you mean to extract digits part out of the string:

You can use the string slice because the pattern is fixed:

```
>>> 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE185.TBL'[17:20]
'185'
```

or, you can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) with [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) (`''.join` is not required if you use Python 2.x)

```
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE185.TBL'))
'185'
```

or, using regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'\d+', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE185.TBL').group()
'185'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the elements you wish to collect are the ones started by 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE' you could slice the strings while iterating the list so that the piece of the string matches the keyword you're searching for, for instance like this:

```
>>> lst = ['15g', 'engout', 'ImpactTphase.py', 'LANL.INI', 'OUTGRAF.TXT', 'OUTPAR.TXT', 'par.bat', 'pargraf1.BAT', 'parphase.py', 'RFFLD000.TBL', 'RFFLD010.TBL', 'sp4.acc', 'Tablplot.log', 'tape2.t2', 'tape3.t3', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE185.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE190.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE195.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE200.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE205.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE210.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE215.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE220.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE225.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE230.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE235.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE240.TBL', 'TplotPRF.TXT']
>>> s = len('TIMESTEPEMITTANCE')
>>> [x for x in lst if x[:s]=='TIMESTEPEMITTANCE']
['TIMESTEPEMITTANCE185.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE190.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE195.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE200.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE205.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE210.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE215.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE220.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE225.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE230.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE235.TBL', 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE240.TBL']
```

Well in the digits case you could use .join() and .isdigit() like this to obtain the number:

```
>>> int(''.join(c for c in 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE240.TBL' if ele.isdigit()))
240
```

Another way would be using regular expressions.

To check if the extension is the same you could check if extension is in the string:

```
>>> if '.TBL' in 'TIMESTEPEMITTANCE240.TBL' ...
```

Comment: You can use `str.startswith` which does not require slice and length calculation; but this does not check for the suffix and the number of digits.

Comment: Well I guess it could as well be easily achieved by matching patterns using regular expressions.